# Ensuring Users Have Completed Prior Form Before Progressing To The Next Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

Ive got a large questionnaire for users to complete. Because its so big I decided to break it into three separate forms on three consecutive pages.

The urls are: questionnaire/section_1, questionnaire/section_2, questionnaire/section_3.

After submitting each form, the form data is saved to the database, and after the final (3rd) form, the three forms are saved as a single pdf for that user. Its important that users complete each of the three questionnaires.

My problem is that users will be able to use the address bar to type www.website/questionnaire/section_3 and complete just the third section, skipping the first two and submitting an incomplete questionnaire.

I cant think of any way to restrict users from accessing later parts of the form until prior parts have been successfully validated and saved.

PS - I have thought about setting permission for each of the three forms, adding permissions to the user once they have submitted one form, but I feel this is hacky??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I ended up dealing with this.

```
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'registered_user'])
def page_two(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormTwoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.formtwo)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('page_three')
    else:
        # redirect if user didnt access the page from personal_information
        if(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') != request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('form_one'))):
            return redirect('form_one')

        else:
            form = FormTwoForm(instance=request.user.formtwo)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, 'example/form_two.html', context)



@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'registered_user'])
def form_three(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormThreeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.formthree)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()

           return redirect('form_four')
    else:
        # redirect if user didnt access the page from needs_analysis
        if(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') != request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('form_two'))):
            return redirect('form_two')

        form = FormThreeForm(instance=request.user.formthree)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, 'example/form_four.html', context)
```